# Little to big endian using multiplication and division - MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, endianness, bit-shift, multiplication

I have a school assignment that requires me to convert a word from little endian to big endian in three different ways. One of them is by using multiplication and division. I know that shifting to the left multiplies the number by 2 but i still cant figure out how to utilise that.

Here is me doing it using rotate. Can someone help me step on this and do it with division and multiplication?

```
.data

.text
.globl main

main:   li $t0,0x11223344 #number to be converted in t0

    rol $t1,$t0,8

    li $t2,0xFF00FF00 #mask in $t2
    and $t3,$t1,$t2

    ror $t1,$t0,8

    li $t2,0x00FF00FF #mask in $t2
    and $t1,$t1,$t2

    or $t3,$t3,$t1

    ror $t3,$t3,16

    li $v0,10
    syscall
```

I cant seem to convert the rotates to shifts correctly. I am doing for rol $t1,$t0,8:

```
#rol $t1,$t0,8
loop:   beq $t1,8,exit #branch to exit if t5=8
    addi $t5,$t5,1 #t5++
    srl $t1, $t0, 1 #shift original word 1 bit to the right
    sll $t2, $t0, 31 #shift original word 31 bits to the left
    or $t1, $t1, $t2
```

but it is not correct.

Help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: First convert your code to shift instead of rotate. Then convert your shifts to multiplication/division.

Comment: @Jester I cant convert it to shifts correctly. I uploaded my attempt.

Comment: There is really no point in using rotates to start with so you can write the code with shifts from scratch. `out=(in << 24) | ((in & 0xff00) << 8) | ((in & 0xff0000) >> 8) | (in >> 24)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda late, but i made this program using only multiplication and division instead of rotate and shift. I hope it helps.

```
  .data
```

test: .space 4
        .text
    .globl main
main:
    li $t0, 0x11223344

```
la $t1, test
sw $t0, ($t1)
```

## start of conversion

```
mul $t1, $t0, 256
li $t2, 0x00FF0000 # $t2 contains mask 0x00FF0000
and $t3, $t1, $t2 # byte 2 valid
div $t1, $t0, 256
li $t2, 0x0000FF00 # $t2 contains mask 0x0000FF00
and $t1, $t1, $t2 # byte 1 valid
or $t3, $t3, $t1
mul $t1, $t0, 16777216
li $t2, 0xFF000000 # $t2 contains mask 0xFF000000
and $t1, $t1, $t2 # byte 3 valid
or $t3, $t3, $t1
div $t1, $t0, 16777216
li $t2, 0x000000FF # $t2 contains mask 0x000000FF
and $t1, $t1, $t2 # byte 0 valid
or $t3, $t3, $t1 # little endian-number in $t3
la $t1, test
sw $t3, ($t1) # store to address pointed by label test

jr $ra
```